# How to place tab bar on top of the view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an iPhone app where I want to place tab bar on top.

Here is my code

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    tabBarController.view.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[[DemoView alloc] init], [[DemoView alloc] init], nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = arr;

    [tabBarController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.tabBar];
```

But I cant see tab bar. I don't what the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to add tabBar over another view ? You can make use of UIToolBar

Comment: try [self.view bringSubviewToFront:tabBarController];   your tabbar might have got overlapped with some other view.

Comment: now the I can see the bar. But when i click it does not do anything

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to take another view to add tabBar. You can directly add to your window

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
UITabBarController *tabC = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabC.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70);

NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:firstObj,secObj, nil];

tabC.viewControllers = arr;

[self.window addSubview:tabC.view];
```